# I have uploaded apple-app-site-association on my server, which I use for backend services

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, aasa

Where can I upload 'apple-app-site-association' for universal link setup in my iOS app?.

How can I use universal link in my iOS app?. I am getting just confuse to read a lot of tutorials. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to upload apple-app-site-association file to the root directory of the server(from where you need to redirect to your installed app).

e.g- Suppose you have to redirect from www.abc.com/getapp then you need to upload the apple-app-site-association file to the root directory where the www.abc.com is get hosted.

**Steps to support universal links-**

1. Create your apple-app-site-association file(Suppose your universal link is www.abc.com/getapp and you want to redirect in your app from here).

   ```
   {
    "applinks": {
       "apps": [],
       "details": [
           {
               "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc", //9JA89QQLNQ is your team ID & com.apple.wwdc is your bundle id
               "paths": [ "/getapp"]
           }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. Upload this file to the root directory where www.abc.com is hosted.
3. Validate at http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/. If the file is valid then all checks would be green.
4. Now prepare your app to support universal links-

   a. Go to developer.apple.com and enable Associated Domains to your app ID.

   b. Select your target and turn on Associated Domains switch.

   c. Add `applinks:abc.com`.
   [image]

   d. Add `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` app delegate method so that your app can receive a link and handle it appropriately.

**Not getting callback to the app-**

1.When a user is browsing your website in Safari and they tap a universal link to a URL in the same domain as the current webpage, iOS respects the user’s most likely intent and opens the link in Safari. 
[image]

2.Copy and paste your universal link(`http(s)://www.abc.com/getapp`) to notes and tap on it. It your app can handle this link you will get the option `Open in "AppName"`.

**References-**

1. https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Hope it may help.

Comment: i did uploaded apple-app-site-association file to server , which i used for backend services like login, signup etc.

Comment: After then, which url will i use for universal link like my server apple-app-site-association url or my custom domain which i create when turn on the Associated Domain in capability in my project

Comment: To implement universal links you need a website. When your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your website opens the content in Safari, as users expect and if the app is installed your app will be opened.

Comment: You can also validate your apple-app-site-association here. https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

Comment: I uploaded apple-app-site-association to my website root directory , then i check apple-app-site-association validate from given link. It shows all green success message. Then which is the my app universal link ? . Please help me i completely got confuse.

Comment: Thank you sir,   Currently i am follow same steps as you mention.

Comment: But sir one thing i want to know , Should all check would be green when we validate the AASA file ?

Comment: Yes.. all check will be green and your apple-app-site-association file would be shown if your file is valid and uploaded successfully. You can type facebook.com in the validator and see the results.

Comment: ok sir , But my AASA file one check getting error "Your file's 'content-type' header was not found or was not recognized.".

Comment: Our site has passed validation at branch.io but it incorrectly indicated a "pass". In fact it still failed the validation at the Apple validator (which gave no useful feedback). The only validator we found that gave truly accurate feedback was here: https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/.